# How to make an array of UIImageViews at class level in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimageview

When I try to make an array with UIImageView s declared as `@IBAction` I receive the "Cannot use instance member within property initializer, property initializers run before self is available" compiler error. How do I workaround this?

[image: Xcode Image *REVISED]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error explains, you can't use instance members when you initialize the property outside of a method at the class level. Leave your array initializer at the class level and add your properties to it within a method.

```
var imageViews = [UIImageView]()

override func viewDidLoad(){
    imageViews = [pos_1,pos2]

    //or
    imageViews.append(pos_1)
    imageViews.append(pos_2)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared imageViews as a constant (a separate issue) then redeclared it again in viewDidLoad. You shouldn't need to redeclare it (or you could just declare once in viewDidLoad)

Comment: It currently works it viewDidLoad. I would like to take it out of viewDidLoad so it can be used in 2 separate methods (one of which being viewDidLoad).

Comment: Just declare it at the head of the class.  Then in viewDidLoad, go straight to your For/In loop as you have (i.e. remove the re-declaration there).

Comment: I'd like to up vote this answer, as it really it correct. The only thing missing for a great answer is *why*, and in light of the OP's comment, what the *real* issue is - variable scope. Add that, and this nails it.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but that is not the solution. Please see my revised picture in the original post. The same error occurs, even without the multiple declarations and changing it from a constant to a variable.

Comment: It appears you've initialized pos1_1 and the other variables in the array elsewhere. And now you're trying to assign those instances in this array to imageViews.  Try:

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too early: 
    let pos1_1 = ... //your declaration

    func tryThis(){
   
    let imagesViews = [pos1_1, ....] 
    for view in imagesViews
    {
        ...//your code
    }

and add trythis() to viewDidLoad